# Post request not working on plesk while working on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, plesk

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm trying to make a api that saves images. I'd send a post request to the api with the image in body and it saves to the static folder 'public/images'.

**Problem:** I tried to do this on localhost and it works perfectly. I've got the cross-origin error's before but I've fixed them. After I hosted the api on plesk, it doesn't save the image, or send a error message back. I've checked the logs on plesk and it says that it received the post request. but it's not doing anything with it.

**front-end code on client-side (hosted on plesk):**

```
const formData = new FormData();
var fileField = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
formData.append('image', fileField.files[0]);
const result = await fetch('https://cdn.dhulun.com/upload25single', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
      }).then(res => res.json())

      if (result.status === "ok") {
         console.log("Success");
         window.location.href = '/';
      } else if (result.status === "error") {

        console.log("error", result.error)

      } else {
        console.log("Something went wrong...")
      }
```

**back-end code on api (hosted on plesk):**

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors')

dotenv.config();

// CONNECT TO DATABASE
async function connectDB() {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT, 
        { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
        () => {
            console.log("Connected to Portal Base [Server]")
        });
    }
connectDB();

var Media = require('./models/media')

// INIT APP
const app = express();
app.use(cors())

// STATIC FILES
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/image', express.static('./public/images'))

// RULES

// INIT MULTER

// Storage Engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './public/images',
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        return cb(null, `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`)
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: { fileSize: 8000000 },
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
});


app.post('/upload25single', upload.single('image'), async(req, res) => {
    
    var image_url = `http://localhost:2525/image/${req.file.filename}`;
    console.log({ 
        status: 'ok',
        image_url: image_url,
    })
    res.json({ 
        status: 'ok',
        image_url: image_url,
    });

 /* var location = req.body.location;
    var category = req.body.category;
    var sourceby = req.body.sourceby;
    var tags = req.body.tags;

    const media = new Media({
        url: image_url,
        location: location,
        category: category,
        source_by: sourceby,
        tags: tags
    });

    try {

        const saved = await media.saved();

        res.json({ 
            status: 'ok',
            image_url: image_url,
        });

    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ 
            status: 'error',
            err: error,
        });
    }
*/
})


function errHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        res.json({
            status: 'error',
            err: err.message
        })
    }
}

// ERROR HANDLING
app.use(errHandler)


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 2525, () => console.log("Server Started..."));
```

I get this error on the browser console (hosted on plesk): `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`
When i click the code line number in the log i got sent to this line:
`console.log("Something went wrong...")`

**EDIT:** I got suggested to turn `res.json()` to `res.text()` and i got this:

```
<p>iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.</p><pre style="background-color: eeeeee">HRESULT: 0x6d
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1013
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error</pre><p>You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because <a href=https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config>system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled</a> configuration setting is 'true'.</p><p>In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using <a href=http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/11/debug-nodejs-applications-on-windows.html>debugging</a> and <a href=http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/09/using-event-tracing-for-windows-to.html>ETW traces</a> to further diagnose the problem.</p><p>The last 64k of the output generated by the node.exe process to stderr is shown below:</p><pre style="background-color: eeeeee">(node:7696) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
```

**Using Node.Js:** Express & Multer

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is the response you're getting back from your `POST https://cdn.dhulun.com/upload25single` call?

Comment: i got suggested to turn `res.json()` to `res.text()` and i got something. i edited the post.

Comment: That's the reason why you are getting the error. Because the service call is returning an HTTP 500 response along with an HTML response body as opposed to a JSON formatted response body which is what you are expecting. You would want to first make sure you are making a proper service call.